# Ошибка при входе в систему

Tags: ubuntu

Установил Ubuntu 11.10 amd 64 desktop. Всё вроде правильно, но пишет

> error: invalild arch independent ELF magic. grub rescue>.

Что это значит? Память 4 ГБ, проц. i5-2400 cpu @ 3100 GHz. Семёрка x64 работает, а Линух x64 не хочет.

Comment: Вывод команды set. И это не ошибка, при входе grub не может загрузить ядро.

Comment: Я мало в этом понимаю. Это проблема с компом или с образом ОС?

Comment: Это проблема с загрузчиком ОС.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте загрузиться с загрузочного диска или флэшки и в терминале выполнить команды:

```
sudo fdisk -ul /dev/sda
```

Смотрите, какие разделы вы используете, и монтируете их (исключая своп), например:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

Затем устанавливаете *grub-efi* и обновляете *grub*:

```
apt-get install grub-efi-amd64
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

Comment: тут ключевое слово Установил те с партициями все нормально. трабла скорее всего в файле menu.lst или какой нибуть встроенный рейд включен